# Can't get CSS3 animation to work on my website

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get a bouncing mouse animation to work on my website.
The exact same code works on another website, whereas on mine it just doesn't do anything.

Here's the css:

```
.mouse {  
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 32px; 
    color: #fff;
    z-index:9999;
    position: absolute;
    color: #e8e8e8;;
    bottom: 240px;
}   
.mouse i {
    -webkit-animation: todown 1.2s infinite linear;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#x11" class="mouse">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down icon-option"></i>
</a>
```

On this website you can see the scrolldown icon I'm trying to create: http://noxxar.com/demo/uralco/

Comment: Where are your keyframes for `todown`?

Comment: Also, you need to look at the proper prefixes for cross browser animation compatibility. `-moz-`, `-webkit-` etc.

Comment: Keyframes? I don't know how to set those. 

I'll add the others as well once it's working (moz webkit etc)

Comment: This is the animated arrow I'm trying to recreate: http://themeforest.net/item/mobius-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/8467936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use CSS animations you need to define [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Luckily the CSS on the theme you linked isn't minified or anything, so you can just copy/paste the parts you want to recreate.

Since Firefox 15 the -moz vendor prefix isn't needed but Chrome and other Webkit Browser still need -webkit-animation: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

**CSS:**

```
#to-slider-scrollto i {
    -webkit-animation: todown 1.2s infinite linear;
    animation: todown 1.2s infinite linear;
}

#to-slider-scrollto i:hover {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes todown {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes todown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateY(15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(15px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

[Working codepen demo](http://codepen.io/zeitwidrig/pen/raRRve) with only the needed CSS

Answer (score 0):

Check out cross browser compatibility

```
.mouse i {
     -webkit-animation: todown 1.2s linear infinite;
      animation: todown 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes todown {
    0% {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
  50% {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
        transform: translateY(5px);
 }
}

@keyframes todown {
  0% {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
 }
 50% {
       -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
        transform: translateY(5px);
  }
}
```